# Block sending mails

Tags: c#

I am a windows forms programmer. We generally programme functionality into a user control.
And many time functionality requires to send an email.

I want to do some thing like :- if i set up the flag "This application is running in testing mode". Then all mail sent form the application (from any of the user control)
should be blocked.

Remember i dont want to do any changes in my existing user controls. or the mail sending lib. I want this to be done only in the container or rather in the Program.cs file.

Thanks

Comment: consider my application as a big container. I want to monitor whatever happens in it for example some one is senidng mail. So any solution at the application level and not at the mail lib.(thats already written) or at control level is a welcome solution for me .Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Inversion of Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973811.aspx).  Have, e.g. a IMailer interface, implemented by RealMailer and TestingMailer.  RealMailer will actually send an email, while TestingMailer will silently drop mails.  Configure a Production configuration that injects RealMailer, and Testing configuration that injects TestingMailer.

Answer (score 0):

Those kind of setting should go in your app.config file, in this case smtp server address. then simply change that value to empty for test environment so your mail is going nowhere.

Comment: i support that answer, BUT my requirement is to block it by some other means. since we dont use smtp address , we dont really use smtp address in appconfig. The library take care of that. and i dont have control over it. so wanted to do it at my end.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to turn it off for local debugging then you can do this.

```
#if DEBUG
    CallMethod();
#endif
```

Otherwise, Matthew Flaschen's answer works well.